# Prevent names in dataframe list from disappearing

Tags: r, list, dataframe

So I initialize a list, which I want to fill with dataframes:

```
listz <- vector("list",2)
```

I also want to keep the dataframes' names around, so I assign them:

```
listzNames <- c("frame1","frame2")
names(listz) <- listzNames
```

The problem is, with every reassignment I make to the dataframes, the names go NULL:

```
listz <- list(data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3),
           data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6))

> names(listz)
NULL
```

I know why this happens, but what would be a neat alternative to reassigning the names at every dataframe reassignment?

Comment: You could name them at the point of assignment: `listz <- list(frame1 = data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3), frame2 = data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6))`

Comment: Yep, but it is not convenient if I'm running a series of lapply functions on the list, reassigning it to the same name every time. I want to munge the dataframes while keeping their names.

Comment: `lapply`  should preserve the list names.

Comment: I see, @mnel! My mistake was to assign names before first assigning the dataframes to the list. If I do it after that the names stay even after I do listz <- lapply(... :D

Comment: Yes. You could initialize the name and then do list[[1]] <- data.frame(...); list[[2]] <- data.frame(...). But this would be more typing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you assign

```
listz <- list(data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3),
           data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6))
```

You are replacing the object formerly defined as `listz`, it is a new object, unrelated to any previous objects of that name.

Therefore  is no need to initialize the list in this case

you have (at least) four options for setting names of a list

### option 1 - `setNames`

```
# Option 1 - using setNames
listz <- setNames(list(data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3),
           data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6)), listzNames)
```

### option 2 - name as you go

```
# Option 2 - naming the list as you go
listz <- list(frame1 = data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3),
           frame2 = data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6))
```

### option 3 - `Hmisc` and `llist`

```
# If your data.frames already exist
# use the llist function in Hmisc, which names the list
# using the names of the object in each element
library(Hmisc)
frame1 <- data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3)
frame2 <- data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6)

listz <- llist(frame1,frame2)
```

### option 4 - prexisting using setNames and get

```
# if your data.frames already exist in the global environment then
# you can use
listz <- setNames(lapply(listzNames, get),listzNames)
```

### option 5 initializing the list (I don't like this)

```
listz <- vector("list",2)
names(listz) <- listzNames
listz[[1]] <- data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3)
listz[[2]] <- data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6)
```

I don't like this option, it requires more typing and therefore more chance of errors!

## Note about `lapply`

`lapply` will preserve any names

```
lapply(listz,head,n=1)

#$frame1
#  id hat
#1  1   1
#
#$frame2
#  id hat
#1  4   4
```

Comment: +1 Wow, that's a complete list of ways to do this!  (Though even as I type this, I wonder if anyone will add any more in the comments...)

Answer (score 2):

Option 6 :)

```
listz[] <- list(data.frame("id" = 1:3, "hat" = 1:3),
                data.frame("id" = 4:6, "hat" = 4:6))
```